# Rename Model that is used as a superclass in another model

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a class `FirstName` that I need to rename to `SecondName`, but this class is also used as a base class for other models.

```
# file 1
class FirstName(models.Model):
    pass # stuff


# file 2
from firstfile.models import FirstName

class ProxyModel(FirstName):
    pass # stuff
```

I tried updating the model name and all references to it...

```
# file 1
class SecondName(models.Model):
    pass # stuff


# file 2
from firstfile.models import SecondName

class ProxyModel(SecondName):
    pass # stuff


# migration
operations = [
    migrations.RenameModel(
        old_name='FirstName',
        new_name='SecondName',
    ),
]
```

But when I run `makemigrations` or 'migrate' I get an error:

> ```
> django.db.migrations.exceptions.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve
> bases for [<ModelState:
> 'my_app.ProxyModel'>] This can happen if you are
> inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g. contrib.auth)  in
> an app with no migrations;
> ```

It seems I cannot import the renamed base model before migration, but I cannot migrate until I resolve the base class issue...

I did already try using the previous model name for the Proxy base class, but get model not found error. I also tried to comment out the proxy model, but still got the error (I think because of the migrations already run for that proxy model).

How can I get around this rename dependency loop?

Python 2.7, Django 1.11

Answer (score -1):

Instead of renaming the table in the database, why not use `db_table` meta property?

```
class SecondName(models.Model):
    pass # stuff

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'app_firstname'
```

Comment: In this case are you creating a new class SecondName and mapping it to the FirstName table? We do want the subclasses to inherit from the new class name SecondName.